# Getting home made vegan energy bars to bind

Tags: cooking

I use a silicon mould tray to make biscuits, snack sized bars. I have used a few recipes, which for taste seem to work (both raw and baked). But my recurring problem is to get the ingredients to bind so the 'bars' remain sufficiently stable for transport and when holding them. Typical ingredients are crushed nuts, dried fruits, maple syrup, cacao, flour form of nuts, oats etc.

So, what are suitable vegan binding ingredients ?

Comment: are they raw or cooked? Can you detail your procedure? Any dietary or health restrictions other than vegan (ingredients to avoid)?

Comment: try ground flax

Comment: Thank you Zanna, cooked and raw. I exclude gluten.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't eggs used in non-vegan recipes as binding agents? Maybe you can try a vegan egg substitute such as Namaste's Egg Replacer.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a cereal/energy snack bar with egg in the ingredients, but I guess egg replacer would probably work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to find an equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Dates and figs are vegan and can work as a binder.

Some commercial energy bars use dates as binders, and figs should work as well.

Dates and figs also have the benefit of being tasty and fibrous.

Because they are sweet, they can help ensure energy bars taste good.

In many regions of the world, they are inexpensive compared to many other common ingredients.

Comment: The vegan status of figs is a subject of debate because of this: https://www.treehugger.com/are-there-really-wasps-your-figs-4868822 (Are there really dead wasps in your figs?)

Answer (score 2):

I've found you should stick with dates or figs. I've made my share of energy bars that turned into granola using anything else.

Answer (score 2):

One binder I've used is **sugar!**
Instead of adding your sugar as-is, boil it on the stove until the hard crack stage (or earlier if you want it more chewy), and then add your additives to that and pour into (heatproof) moulds. I've made energy bars like this with great success. It's like brittle (eg [recipe](https://lovingitvegan.com/vegan-peanut-brittle/)) but you add more stuff so the ratio of stuff-to-brittle is higher.

My recipe also used milk powder (not vegan) but it probably isn't needed:

- boil sugar on stove
- dump in oats,nuts, milk powder and whatever other additives
- pour into heatproof, greased, foil-lined mould, leave to set and cut into bars.